# How to save date student's absence in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date

I have student table in SQL Server.

In my web application I have `textBox`, where I can input a date (`dd-mm-yyyy`). This date means that any(application know which exactly) student was absent this day.

How to save this date in SQL Server?

There is no problem when student is absent just one day per all life, because I can create one additional column in my student table and save there date of absent.

But I don't know how many days student will absent. I can add thousand columns to my student table and write in there dates of absents, but it's very bad solution.

So, how to save dates of absence in SQL?

I wrote my web application in ASP.NET, C#, SQL Server.

Comment: Parse it to `DateTime` and save it to `datetime2` column type in your sql server.

Comment: Ever heard of Foreign Key and one to many relationship?

Comment: I know what is Foreign Key, I know less about relationship. I thought to create one table additionally for every student, but if I will have 100 students I would have create additionally 100 `absent` tables, it's not good idea. I didn't know why I didn't think about one common table for all students :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create another table called **absents** with three columns:

- id (primary index and auto_increment)
- student_id (should not be unique)
- date

The id column is just the id of the absent (it's a good practice to have id for every row on a table). The student_id is a reference to id column of students table, identifying the correct student. And the date column is the date of absent.

Another good practice is to create relationship internally and set triggers to actions like delete (what should you do if the student is deleted?).

Comment: now I have delete button, which delete student from student table. if I create absents table I can add lower second delete like(DELETE FROM absents WHERE student_id='student id whose I'm deleting'). But if it's possible to delete student, automatically delete absents this student thanks relationship I will do so, but first I must learn more about it.

Comment: You should google for something like "MySQL foreign key delete cascade". It's also a good idea to learn about the differences of innoDB and myisam (I'm not sure, but I believe foreign keys doesn't work on myisam tables). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have another table to keep track of the dates the student was absent.

Say your current table is as follows:

```
Student
-------
StudentId [PK]
...
```

So you would now create another table as:

```
StudentAbsent
-------
StudentAbsentId [PK]
StudentId [FK, Student.StudentId]
AbsentDate
```

To get the dates the student with `id=5` was absent you'd do something like the following in SQL

```
SELECT AbsentDate FROM StudentAbsent
WHERE StudentId = 5
```

---

Oh and BTW you'd want to read more on relationships. If it's a **1-1 relationship** one row of `table1` is related to one row of `table2`.
If it's a **1-n relationship**, one row of `table1` is related to many rows of `table2` (as is the case above)
If it's a **n-n relationship**, one row of `table1` is related to many rows of `table2` and vice-versa.